# How to remove the default margin on the content of a wpf TabItem in C# Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the TabControl class in WPF and I've noticed that the content of each TabItem has a default margin of 4 pixels on all sides.

I'm building the Tab Control Dynamically in C# code, but I've only seen the XAML solution below. How is this achievable in C# code or Templating.

```
<TabItem>
  <Grid Margin="-4">
  </Grid>
<TabItem>
```

[image: Tab Border]

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a grid id, for example (pertinent to you case):

```
  <Grid Name ="grd">
  </Grid>
```

then apply margin spec like the following:

```
grd.Margin = new Thickness(-4);
```

Also, you can use a variation of this syntax:

```
grd.Margin = new Thickness(-4,-4,-4,-4);
```

The same technique you can apply to other controls. Read more on this topic (Wpf Margin) at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx

Hope this will help.

Comment: That's XAML though, the TabControl is Dynamically Generated in Code.

Comment: I have answered your original question in regards to setting the margin of Wpf controls dynamically. If you have more questions (like how to add Wpf controls dynamically, etc.), then please put them in separate post. Thanks and regards,

Comment: @user937036 WPF doesn't use IDs, it uses the Name attribute, instead, which you add directly to the XAML markup for that tag.  From there, you can assign property values like Alex demonstrated in the main function of the code-behind (.cs) file of your XAML page.